# Multiple Nancy route patterns to a single action?

Tags: nancy

I would like to have the same action be performed by 2 or more route patterns.

For example:

```
//Route 1: 
Get["/{category}/{product_name}/{id}"]

// Route 2:
Get["/api/products/{id}"]
```

Ideally the first route would be SEO friendly and return a view, the second route would return JSON and be used as an API.

Is it simply a matter of defining 2 separate routes and calling the common logic encapsulated in another method? Or is there some Nancy magic I don't know about?

**Update**
My final solution was to use multiple assignments in the one statement.

```
Get["/{category}/{product_name}/{id}"] = Get["/api/products/{id}"] = params => 
{
   ...
};
```

Comment: I like your solution which is what I also implemented. Could you put it down a proposed solution so it can be voted on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of calling the common logic. No magic I'm afraid.
Note that Nancy's content negotiation can take care of returning a view or json based on the request.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is answered, but I thought I'd add my tuppence for a slightly neater solution. This is my solution:

```
public class ExampleModule : NancyModule
    {
        public ExampleModule()
        {
            Get["/somepath"] = DoSomething;
            Post["/somepath"] = DoSomething;
        }

        private dynamic DoSomething(dynamic parameters)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```